# How to escape querySelector to support HTML5 IDs

Tags: javascript, css, html

The [HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name) and [this post](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class) states that HTML ID tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens (-), underscores (_), colons (:), and periods (.).

In `HTML5` you can now use any characters, as long as there is at least one character and no spaces are used.

It's tricky enough to escape the charactors for CSS code, but my question is, how do I write a method that can safely escape the selector so it can be used in `document.querySelector` without throwing an error?

**EDIT**

I know that you use backslash to escape a special character, but my question really boils down to: how do I determine which characters need escaping. A regex would be nice.

Comment: Something like this perhaps `'#' + text.replace(/[^a-z|\d]/gi, '\\$&');`

Answer (score 1):

You can scape by using the slashes:

```
document.querySelector('#id\\<<meta character>>');
```

For eg:

```
document.querySelector('#id\\:title');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use slash() to escape it, but since `\` itself is a escape character you need to use `\\`

for `my#id`, `my\\#id`

- [Characters and case](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters)
- [Characters and case sensitivity](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#case-sensitive)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var numericId = '123456';
var escapedSelector = '#' + CSS.escape(numericId);
var div = document.querySelector(escapedSelector);
div.style.color = 'orange';
```

```html
<div id="123456">
  The orginal color was not orange.
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).